# Generate report with chart and save it to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, charts

I am developing application wich produce a report with graph. I read about free C# libraries to create PDF but I can't see any completely FREE geenrator to use in application that I want to sell. Can you give me one?

Other problem is to generate a simple chart. What are the tools to create such a graph? I need to put it into pdf document after generating it.

Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

PDF reporting could be done using nfop. I know someone who has done PDF with that, but I do not know more.

Regarding the charting: you could use Microsoft Chart controls, render to an image and include an image in the PDF.